# wp_nav_menu change sub-menu class name?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to change the child `<ul class="sub-menu">` generated by WordPress itself to a custom class name?

I know the parent `<ul>` you can remove or change the name with `'menu_class' => 'newname'`.

I couldn't find the answer. Itried `'submenu_class' => 'customname'`. It seems logic to me, but obviously that is no the right one.

any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to change your CSS?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

There is no option for this, but you can extend the 'walker' object that WordPress uses to create the menu HTML. Only one method needs to be overridden:

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"my-sub-menu\">\n";
  }
}
```

Then you just pass an instance of your walker as an argument to `wp_nav_menu` like so:

```
'walker' => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu()
```

Comment: i'd check first if $depth is the correct one. you don't want to have a messed up menu if some ads a new level to the custom menu

Comment: I think I'm being a tool but I cannot seem to get this to work! I've inserted the `class` section of the code in the `functions.php` file & the second section is referenced as part of the `$defaults` array within `wp_nav_menu()`. Is this correct?

Comment: @Richard M do you know if this debug error is fixable? I tried with the string below and it caused problems. How can I edit your answer above to conform to this standard?

 PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of My_Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl() should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array)

Comment: @Drai I also got that warning and solved with this little tweak.
`class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"mp-level\">\n";
  }
}`

Comment: On WP 4.7 the code become : ```class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
 function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
  if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
   $t = '';
   $n = '';
  } else {
   $t = "\t";
   $n = "\n";
  }
  $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
  $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul class=\"my-sub-menu\">{$n}";
 }
}```

Comment: Please see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666092/1694902. Maybe this resource wasn't available by the time the best answer was written, but I think it's a cleaner way to achieve what was asked.

Answer (score 24):

This is an old question and I'm not sure if the solution I'm going to mention was available by the time you asked, but I think it's worth mentioning. You can achieve what you want by adding a filter to `nav_menu_submenu_css_class`. See the example below - you can replace `my-new-submenu-class` by the class(es) you want:

```
function my_nav_menu_submenu_css_class( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = 'my-new-submenu-class';
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'my_nav_menu_submenu_css_class' );
```

Answer (score 23):

Choice of options.

1. Switch the 'echo' argument to false and you can replace the class names.

```php
    echo str_replace('sub-menu', 'menu menu_sub', wp_nav_menu( array(
        'echo' => false,
        'theme_location' => 'sidebar-menu',
        'items_wrap' => '<ul class="menu menu_sidebar">%3$s</ul>' 
      ) )
    );
```

2. Since WP 4.8 we can use the [nav_menu_submenu_css_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) filter.

```php
add_filter( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'my_custom_submenu_classnames', 10, 3 );
/**
 * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
 *
 * @param string[] $classes Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
 * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
 * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 * @return string[]
 */
function my_custom_submenu_classnames( $classes, $args, $depth ) {
    // Here we can additionally use menu arguments.
    if ( 'header-menu' === $args->theme_location ) {
        $default_class_name_key = array_search( 'sub-menu', $classes );
        if ( false !== $default_class_name_key ) {
            unset( $classes[ $default_class_name_key ] );
        }
        $classes[] = 'header-submenu';
        $classes[] = "depth-{$depth}";
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

3. Custom Menu walker:

```
class My_Nav_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        // ! You default class names.
        $classes = array( 'sub-menu', 'my-class' );
        // ! Example of using arguments.
        if ( 'header-menu' === $args->theme_location ) {
            $default_class_name_key = array_search( 'sub-menu', $classes );
            if ( false !== $default_class_name_key ) {
                unset( $classes[ $default_class_name_key ] );
            }
            $classes[] = 'header-submenu';
            $classes[] = "depth-{$depth}";
        }

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 4.8.0
         *
         * @param string[] $classes Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul{$class_names}>{$n}";
    }
}
```

It remains to include the file with an custom walker and point it to the menu:

```php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
        'walker'         => new My_Nav_Menu_Walker()
    )
);
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  it still only 'sub-menu'.  no change.

Comment: 'echo' => false,  this is very important!

Comment: Easily the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 14):

You can use WordPress **preg_replace** filter (in your theme functions.php file)
example:

```
function new_submenu_class($menu) {    
    $menu = preg_replace('/ class="sub-menu"/','/ class="yourclass" /',$menu);        
    return $menu;      
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu','new_submenu_class');
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this method is much easier

Answer (score 11):

Here's an update to what Richard did that adds a "depth" indicator. The output is level-0, level-1, level-2, etc.

```
class UL_Class_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"level-".$depth."\">\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a class name to the children of this nest UL?

Comment: Sure! What's an example of a class name you'd want to add?

Comment: In addition to what you've shown above (adding a class to nested UL's) I'd like to add the class 'nav-main-sub-item' to nested LI's.  I've figured out how to add a class 'nav-main-sub-item' to main level LI's and the second level UL's as you've shown above.  But cannot tie them together with a class on the nested LI's.  I actually have an open question on it here if you want to peek in on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941129/how-do-i-add-or-change-an-li-class-name-in-a-wordpress-custom-menu-walker

Comment: This is the answer I needed. By adding the depth, it makes it possible to style different levels  independently. Lots of complicated code out there regarding the walker menu but  this it makes stying the Underscores nav easy. For anyone else out there confused as I was - this is probably what you need. To understand a bit more read this: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to extend the Walker. This will do:

```
function overrideSubmenuClasses( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = 'myclass1';
    $classes[] = 'myclass2';

    return $classes;
}
add_action('nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'overrideSubmenuClasses');
```

Comment: This worked great for me. Keep in mind this function replaces all of the current classes so if you were already using a class don't forget to include it in the array.

Comment: Good point @Jake, I've updated it to append new classes instead of replacing the existing ones.

Answer (score 6):

Like it always is, after having looked for a long time before writing something to the site, just a minute after I posted here I found my solution.

It thought I'd share it here so someone else can find it.

```
//Add "parent" class to pages with subpages, change submenu class name, add depth class

    class Prio_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ){
        $GLOBALS['dd_children'] = ( isset($children_elements[$element->ID]) )? 1:0;
        $GLOBALS['dd_depth'] = (int) $depth;
        parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }

     function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"children level-".$depth."\">\n";
  }
}

add_filter('nav_menu_css_class','add_parent_css',10,2);
function  add_parent_css($classes, $item){
     global  $dd_depth, $dd_children;
     $classes[] = 'depth'.$dd_depth;
     if($dd_children)
         $classes[] = 'parent';
    return $classes;
}

//Add class to parent pages to show they have subpages (only for automatic wp_nav_menu)

function add_parent_class( $css_class, $page, $depth, $args )
{
   if ( ! empty( $args['has_children'] ) )
       $css_class[] = 'parent';
   return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'add_parent_class', 10, 4 );
```

This is where I found the solution:
[Solution in WordPress support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_nav_menu-dropdown-walker)

Answer (score 4):

I had to change:

`function start_lvl(&$output, $depth)`

to:

`function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() )`

Because I was getting an incompatibility error:

`Strict Standards: Declaration of My_Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl() should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array)`

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful to you

**How to add a parent class for menu item**

```
function wpdocs_add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {
$parents = array();

// Collect menu items with parents.
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( $item->menu_item_parent && $item->menu_item_parent > 0 ) {
        $parents[] = $item->menu_item_parent;
    }
}

// Add class.
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( in_array( $item->ID, $parents ) ) {
        $item->classes[] = 'menu-parent-item';
    }
}
return $items;
 }
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpdocs_add_menu_parent_class' );

/**
 * Add a parent CSS class for nav menu items.
 * @param array  $items The menu items, sorted by each menu item's menu order.
 * @return array (maybe) modified parent CSS class.
*/
```

**Adding Conditional Classes to Menu Items**

```
function wpdocs_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if ( is_single() && 'Blog' == $item->title ) {
    // Notice you can change the conditional from is_single() and $item->title
    $classes[] = "special-class";
}
return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class' , 'wpdocs_special_nav_class' , 10, 2 );
```

For reference : [click me](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#source-code)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a Hook

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'some_function', 10, 3 );
function some_function( $classes, $args, $depth ){
    foreach ( $classes as $key => $class ) {
    if ( $class == 'sub-menu' ) {
        $classes[ $key ] = 'my-sub-menu';
    }
}

return $classes;
}
```

where

```
$classes(array) - The CSS classes that are applied to the menu <ul> element.
$args(stdClass) - An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
$depth(int) - Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
```

Comment: Artemiy Egorov please could you write all code inside of function.php thank you!

Comment: Sure. If you want to add classes only to sub menu u can use:
`add_filter( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'some_function', 10, 3 );
function some_function( $classes, $args, $depth ){
foreach ( $classes as $key => $class ) {
  if ( $class == 'sub-menu' ) {
   $classes[ $key ] = 'my-sub-menu';
  }
 }

 return $classes;
}`

Answer (score 0):

in the above i need a small change which i am trying to place but i am not able to do that,
your output will look like this

```
<ul>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="depth0 parent"><a href="#">About Us</a>
<ul class="children level-0">
    <li id="menu-item-17" class="depth1"><a href="#">Sample Page</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-16" class="depth1"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

what i am looking for

```
<ul>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="depth0"><a class="parent" href="#">About Us</a>
<ul class="children level-0">
    <li id="menu-item-17" class="depth1"><a href="#">Sample Page</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-16" class="depth1"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

in the above one i have placed the parent class inside the parent anchor link that `<li id="menu-item-13" class="depth0"><a class="parent" href="#">About Us</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to replace your cutomclass css class name to sub-menu.
use find and replace: ie. find: .customclass replace with .sub-menu,
works for me.

Answer (score -6):

To change the default "sub-menu" class name, there is simple way.
You can just change it in wordpress file.

location  : www/project_name/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php.

open this file and at line number 49, change the name of sub-menu class with your custom class.

Or you can also add your custom class next to sub-menu.

Done.

It worked for me.I used wordpress-4.4.1.

Comment: your answer will only work till WordPress updates their core files. If WordPress releases an update that changes the file you manipulated then your changes will be erased. It's better to create a Walker Nav as suggested above. It's a good rule of thumb to never modify the core files since they can change with core updates.