# change sub-menu class in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When using `wp_nav_menu` in my theme, I want to change Worpdress' default `sub-menu` class for items that contain a child list (to `dropdown` to fit for the Foundation framework).

I have reviewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name) on the topic but I cannot seem to get it to function correctly.

In my `functions.php` file I have inserted:

```php
class My_Sub_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown\">\n";
  }
}
```

And in my `header.php` file I have:

```php
<?php
    $defaults = array(
        'theme_location'  => 'header-nav',
        'menu_class'      => 'right',
        'walker'          => new My_Sub_Menu(),
        'container'       =>  false
    );
    wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
?>
```

But nothing occurs. Am I misunderstanding where to insert the code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it because you haven't specified an `end_lvl` for your `class My_Sub_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu`?

```
class My_Sub_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown\">\n";
  }
  function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Huh, saw no reference of that in the other post! Guess I need to get more familiar with these thing. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You're very welcome, I haven't looked at Walker_Nav_Menu personally, but it was an educated guess.