# wordpress nav submenu class siggning

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

my css is as

```
 <nav class="fluid topmenu">
      <ul class="fluid fluidList menuitems">
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="boxes.html">boxes</a>  
                <ul class="fluid fluidList submenu">
                    <li><a href="small.html">small</a></li>
                    <li><a href="medium.html">MEDIUM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="large.html">large</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </li>
            <li><a href="aboutus.html">ABOUT US</a></li>            
      </ul> 
  </nav>
```

i converted this to wordpress and put the code as

```
<nav class="fluid topmenu">
      <ul class="fluid fluidList menuitems">
         <li><?php wp_nav_menu(
                 array(
                    'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 
                    'menu_class' => 'fluid fluidList submenu', 
                    'container_id' => '',
                    )           
        );?>
    </li>

      </ul> 
  </nav>
```

but in the class submenu isnot applied to the dropdown submenu in wordpress

i did register the menu in functions.php as my main menu is working

plz tell me how to get the class submenu applied to the dropdown of wp_nav_menu submenuitems

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the nav element:

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

and modify the variables with your classes and id's

To modify the subclass you need to add a walker:
[wp_nav_menu change sub-menu class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name)

Comment: which variables shud ibe changing with classes....this is my first attempt at this html to wordpress conversion so sorry for asking this silly question

Comment: @user3117694 You need to add a walker to change the submenu class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name but I would recommend to change the class names in your CSS coz it's easyer

Answer (score 0):

'main-menu', 
      'menu_class' => 'fluid fluidList menuitems', 
      'container_id' => '',
    )           
);?>

Use Jquery to add SubClass.

```
$(".menuitems li").find('ul').addClass('fluid fluidList submenu');
```