# Change Menu class & id when use wp_nav_menu Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, class, nav

The wordpress's wp_nav_menu automatically create class and id for menu.
I want to change the default class and id name from this:

```
<div class="menu-top-container">
<ul id="menu-top" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-8">
```

To this:

```
<div class="my_menu">
<ul id="my_unordered_list">
<li id="my_list_child">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the documentation [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

Comment: Thank! But now i have a new problem. What if i want to change the class of the <ul> inside another <ul>. Something about walk_nav_menu. If you know, please show me how. Thank you.

Comment: See this answer [wp_nav_menu change sub-menu class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the codes page for `wp_nav_menu()`. You'll find the answer there.

'header-menu', 'menu_class' => 'mymenu' ) ); ?>