# How to attach css into drop down elements of menu items in wordpress using walker function?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In plain html a class "dropdown" is attached to the li which has children. and ul under the parent li has class "dropdown-menu". If hover over the parent li it gets another class "open", so that hidden child ul appear and when hover out "open" class being removed from parent li, so the child ul disappear.

As i see in wordpress if an li becomes parent it gets a class "menu-item-has-children", and child ul gets the class "sub-menu", so exploiting this i'm using this code below :

script.js

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('.menu-item-has-children>a').append('<div class="caret"></div>');
        $('.menu-item-has-children').addClass('dropdown');
        $('.sub-menu').addClass('dropdown-menu');

    $('.menu-item-has-children').mouseover(function(){

        $('.menu-item-has-children').addClass('open');

    }).mouseout(function(){

        $('.menu-item-has-children').removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

style.css

---

```
.sub-menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}
```

However i want to achieve it by customising walker class. How do i customize walker function to put
"dropdown" class to parent li and "dropdown-menu" to its child ul ?

Comment: I think maybe you are looking for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the link I've provided in my comment, but you basically need to look at extending the Walker_Nav_Menu class. There's another link here that might prove useful; http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/