# How to filter the sub-menu classname in WordPress navigation menus?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

In WordPress when using navigation menus, second-level menus are given the class `sub-menu`. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a title="Page 1" href="/page-1/">Page 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a title="Sub page 1" href="/sub-page-1/">Sub page 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Sub page 2" href="/sub-page-2/">Sub page 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) so need that classname to be `dropdown-menu`. My attempt so far has been to copy all of the `dropdown-menu` classes from bootstrap.css into my theme's style.css and change their names to `sub-menu`. This isn't a great approach because when I next upgrade Bootstrap, I'll need to check anything hasn't changed.

My next thought was to filter the classname. Does WordPress provide a filter which will let me change this classname?

**Update**

I found a walker solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048792/1709033) which lets me change the `sub-menu` class.

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"my-sub-menu\">\n";
  }
}
```

I'm pasting this directly into my theme's functions.php. This allows me to change the classname but my problem now is I get the following PHP debug notice:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of My_Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl()
>   should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth
>   = 0, $args = Array) in /wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php
>   on line 224

Should I be pasting the walker directly into my theme's functions.php? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to use walker for this...

Comment: Why is a walker needed?

Comment: if you want to change the sub_menu class...I don't think is there any function to change this class in wp. Just for customization in wp menu

Comment: After searching for a walker solution, I found this solution but am not entirely sure how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5048792/1709033 - any ideas? does it go directly in my theme's functions.php?

Comment: If you want it simply then use jquery or javascript to update It. Would you like to do in jquery

Comment: I'd prefer a non-jQuery solution. The walker I linked-to above looks promising I just don't know how exactly to use it.

Comment: I have posted you an answer..please check

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do the opposite? Instead of editing the CSS, edit the theme file. You could just change the ul's class.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   ...
</ul>
```

If you need to keep the "sub-menu" class in the ul for any reason, you can also use both in the same element. Just add the "bootstrap.css" class to the ul.

```
<ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
   ...
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible when working with WordPress nav menus?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your walker file in functions.php and change in your wp_nav_menu function to call walker like this...

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'              => 'Main Navigation',
    'theme_location'    => 'main_navigation',
    'depth'             => 0,
    'container'         => 'div',
    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
);
```

Comment: your function start_lvl in your walker function is not compatible to its parent class Walker_Nav_Menu...so please post your function start_lvl here..

Comment: My `start_lvl` function is inside my `My_Walker_Nav_Menu class`. Actually the solution to the debug notice was also on that page. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name#comment32022827_5048792)