# Remove “sub-menu” class in second Level UL

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I am trying to convert HTML to Wordpress and I am having troubles with menus.

The menu is a 3 level drop-down menu, I am outputting it with `wp_nav_menu` and this is how it formats

```html
<ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>Level 2</li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Level 3</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li>Portfolio</li>
  <li>Contacts</li>
</ul>
```

Basically I want to remove the "sub-menu" class from the /s in the 2nd level and 3rd level.

This is how I want it to be:

```html
<ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <ul class="first-nav">
    <li>Level 2</li>
    <ul class="second-nav">
      <li>Level 3</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li>Portfolio</li>
  <li>Contacts</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems to be a repeat question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name

Comment: i wanna add second level sub-menu class

Comment: If you read the link - it shows a different class at each different level, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/ see `depth`

Answer (score 0):

For converting **html to wordpress** menu. This may be helpful to you.

> wp_nav_menu ( array $args = array() )

**Usage**

```
wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

Given a theme_location parameter, the function displays the menu assigned to that location. If no such location exists or no menu is assigned to it, the parameter fallback_cb will determine what is displayed.

**Adding Conditional Classes to Menu Items**

```
function wpdocs_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if ( is_single() && 'Blog' == $item->title ) {
    // Notice you can change the conditional from is_single() and $item- >title
    $classes[] = "special-class";
}
return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class' , 'wpdocs_special_nav_class' , 10, 2 );
```

For Reference:[click me:](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#source-code)