# How to change class in sub-menu (Wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I would appreciate if you help me, the problem is that I have a menu and it has a submenu, and this submenu has a class by default - sub-menu, how can I change this class to submenu and how can I add to my first li - tag -

HTML:

```
<ul class="cf">
    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="about.html">managers<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-1g" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="managers.html">page one</a></li>
            <li><a href="shareholder.html">page two/a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

PHP:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'menu', 'container'=>'false', 'menu_class'=>'cf', 'depth' => 2)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exaclty what you are trying to do. But you can find the submenu output in the file "wp-includes\class-walker-nav-menu.php".

The menu is build dynamically on the sub-menu class. So i don't know if the menu generator is still working if you change this class. Maybe it is better to add an additional class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('ul.cf').find(".sub-menu").addClass("submenu").removeClass("sub-menu");
            });
```

May be this will work for wordpress. Write this in your theme function.php

```
function change_submenu_class($menu) {  
  $menu = preg_replace('/ class="sub-menu"/','/ class="submenu" /',$menu);  
  return $menu;  
}  
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','change_submenu_class');
```

Comment: I know Js well and how to change it with js, but I thought maybe there is another way to change it using only php

Comment: There is jquery tag in your question so I have done it with jquery

Comment: You can study this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name